# Retrieving taxonomy term url from node in Drupal 7

Tags: url, drupal, drupal-7, taxonomy

I am using Authcache to cache pages for authenticated users and Authcache Actions+Rules to expire node:url + front page from cache whenever a node is created/updated/deleted.
I created a rule event "Before saving content" + 3 actions "Clear cache by path [node:url]" , "Clear cache by path [node:edit-url]" and "Clear cache by path [site:url]"
All nodes are tagged with at least 1 taxonomy term and the node teaser appears on the taxonomy term page. Because of this I need to create a rule to clear cache for the taxonomy term pages tagged in the node. So far I could not find a solution.
Any suggestions on how to create this rule?

Thank you in advance.
Catalin

Answer (score 1):

To load a taxonomy term's url from the tid (which is attached to the node) use:

```
$tid = $node->your_taxonomy_field['und'][0]['tid'];
$taxonomy_term_url = drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'taxonomy/term/'.$tid);
```